# Excel VBA/ export to PDF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, userform

i have a problem with an excel macro, can somebody help to find out the reason?

I have several worksheets (20+) in a big workbook with macros (xlsm).
I wrote a macro enabling the user to select and export some sheets in PDF - the sheets that they find relevant.
They click a button, a UserForm opens, they select the desired Sheet(s) in the UserForm and click OK.
The macro fills a string Array with the selected sheet names (e.g. "Overview", "Page 1", ...).

This module-level array (SelectedSheets) is used by another sub to actually select the sheets in Excel and use the "ExportAsFixedFormat" method.

The problem is: sometimes 1 Worksheet (the last one) is just simply missing from the pdf, although the array is definitely correct- I tested it with the Debug/Watch several times...

The sub which is making problems:

```
Private Sub myPrintToPdf()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SelectedSheets).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=thisworkbook.Path & "\" & left(thisworkbook.Name,len(thisworkbook.Name)-4) & "pdf", OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for any ideas or inputs in advance,

Dan

I tried:

- tested if the array is correct and added a break Point just before the ExportAsFixedFormat method
- removed any print areas on the pages in Excel
- removed some big merged cells on the sheets

Comment: Your issue is within the function that getting the array of sheets, not the myPrintToPdf function.  Post the calling function, please.